# @NamedArg without a field

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2020 and when I do something like:

```
public class MyNode {

    public MyNode(@NamedArg("pane") Pane pane) {
        //<code>
    }

}
```

The following code doesn't work:

```
<MyNode>
    <pane>
        <Pane/>
    </pane>
</MyNode>
```

> Cannot resolve sumbol `pane`

When I change MyNode to:

```
public class MyNode {

    private final Pane pane;

    public MyNode(@NamedArg("pane") Pane pane) {
        //<code>
    }

}
```

It is properly detected.

IMPORTANT: I don't even have to use the field, just initialize it. Is there any workaround to get it working without creating a dummy field just to get it working with FXML?

It doesn't have to be a `Pane` obviously, it can be any other `Object`. For types like `double`, I'm able to get it working without creating a field, like this: `<pane myDoubleValue="100.0"/>`

Comment: The FXML editor in IntelliJ does not exactly match what the `FXMLLoader` is capable of. Try to load the FXML file despite the error in the IDE and, if it works, just ignore the error.

Comment: @Slaw you may be right, whole project compiles and runs just fine. (you should write an answer)

Comment: Hi! Can you please share the project sample where the IntelliJ IDEA doesn't provide the correct highlighting here: https://uploads.services.jetbrains.com/ or attach the sample to the issue created at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/. Thank you

Comment: @OlgaKlisho I just attached the project on intellij-support.jetbrains.com (ticket #2704847)